How can I rebuild my single-user remote repo from the commits in my local repo?
As a new user of git with Visual Studio I got messages that I needed to increase my storage with LFS. I then got messages that I needed to purchase more storage so my git pushes could proceed. I tried to remove all the VS files from my remote repo to regain space, but push kept trying to push my VS files. So I deleted my remote repo, recreated it, then ADDed my source files (.cpp, .h, etc.). My LOCAL repo still has all my branches and commits (because I can display them with git inside VS), but the remote does not. All the searches I have done explain the REVERSE process (recover local from remote), but not what I need (recover remote from local). I would really appreciate it if someone could explain how to properly rebuild my remote or provide a link to that procedure.
I have not tried any git commands, because I cannot find an explanation for what I need.

What happens when you set up your remote as a remote and then push?

Note that deleting the file from the repo does not remove it from the history, so your attempt to push to the remote will probably re-trigger the "too large" error. You will have to remove the large file from the repo history.

short answer is: git push --all --tags. If you first need to change the url for the remote, look at git help remote; you probably want one of git remote add or git remote set-url

git push uploaded some VS files, which I had to delete, but the .git folder did not get uploaded. So I only have my main branch. How can I replace the remote .git folder? All references seem to only work the reverse direction
